# PHP to check Operating System ONLY

Tags: php, windows

I'm using the follow php code to display operating system version:

```
<?php

 $user_agent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

 function getOS() { 

global $user_agent;

$os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";

$os_array       =   array(
                        '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                        '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                        '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                        '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP     x64',
                        '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                        '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                        '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                        '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                        '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                        '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                        '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                        '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                        '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                        '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                        '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                        '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                        '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                        '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                        '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                        '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                        '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
                    );

     foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) { 

    if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
        $os_platform    =   $value;
    }

    }   

      return $os_platform;

       }

 function getBrowser() {

global $user_agent;

$browser        =   "Unknown Browser";

$browser_array  =   array(
                        '/msie/i'       =>  'Internet Explorer',
                        '/firefox/i'    =>  'Firefox',
                        '/safari/i'     =>  'Safari',
                        '/chrome/i'     =>  'Chrome',
                        '/opera/i'      =>  'Opera',
                        '/netscape/i'   =>  'Netscape',
                        '/maxthon/i'    =>  'Maxthon',
                        '/konqueror/i'  =>  'Konqueror',
                        '/mobile/i'     =>  'Handheld Browser'
                    );

   foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) { 

    if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
        $browser    =   $value;
    }

}

 return $browser;

  }


 $user_os        =   getOS();
 $user_browser   =   getBrowser();

  $device_details =   "<strong>Browser: </strong>".$user_browser."<br />                <strong>Operating System: </strong>".$user_os."";

 print_r($device_details);

echo("<br /><br /><br />".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."");

  ?>
```

which give me the following result:

> Browser: Unknown Browser
>   Operating System: Unknown OS Platform

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36

I'm running Windows 10 and it doesnt appear to work.

All I want to display is the following:

> This PC is running Windows 10

is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$os_array` doesn't have any data for Windows 10 (which I'm assuming can be mapped to Windows NT 10.0.

So, simply change `$os_array` to:

```
$os_array       =   array(
                    '/windows nt 10.0/i'    =>  'Windows 10',
                    '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                    '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                    '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                    '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP     x64',
                    '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                    '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                    '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                    '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                    '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                    '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                    '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                    '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                    '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                    '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                    '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                    '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                    '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                    '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                    '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                    '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                    '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
                );
```

### Alternative solution

This is pretty much the same code as yours - just providing an alternative but there's really no reason why this would work but the previous didn't.

```
<?php

function getOS($userAgent) {

$osPlatform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";

$os_array       =   array(
    'windows nt 10.0'    => 'Windows 10',
    'windows nt 6.2'     =>  'Windows 8',
    'windows nt 6.1'     =>  'Windows 7',
    'windows nt 6.0'     =>  'Windows Vista',
    'windows nt 5.2'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
    'windows nt 5.1'     =>  'Windows XP',
    'windows xp'         =>  'Windows XP',
    'windows nt 5.0'     =>  'Windows 2000',
    'windows me'         =>  'Windows ME',
    'win98'              =>  'Windows 98',
    'win95'              =>  'Windows 95',
    'win16'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
    'macintosh|mac os x' =>  'Mac OS X',
    'mac_powerpc'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
    'linux'              =>  'Linux',
    'ubuntu'             =>  'Ubuntu',
    'phone'             =>  'iPhone',
    'pod'               =>  'iPod',
    'pad'               =>  'iPad',
    'android'            =>  'Android',
    'blackberry'         =>  'BlackBerry',
    'webos'              =>  'Mobile'
);

foreach ($os_array as $label => $value) {
    if (stripos($userAgent, $label)) {
        return $value;
    }
}

return $osPlatform;

}

function getBrowser($userAgent) {

$browser        =   "Unknown Browser";

$browser_array  =   array(
    'msie'       =>  'Internet Explorer',
    'firefox'    =>  'Firefox',
    'safari'     =>  'Safari',
    'chrome'     =>  'Chrome',
    'opera'      =>  'Opera',
    'netscape'   =>  'Netscape',
    'maxthon'    =>  'Maxthon',
    'konqueror'  =>  'Konqueror',
    'mobile'     =>  'Handheld Browser'
);

foreach ($browser_array as $label => $value) {
    if (stripos($userAgent, $label)) {
        return $value;
    }
}

return $browser;

}

$userAgent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
//$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36      (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36';


$user_os        =   getOS($userAgent);
$user_browser   =   getBrowser($userAgent);

$device_details =   "<strong>Browser: </strong>".$user_browser."<br />                    <strong>Operating System: </strong>".$user_os."";

print_r($device_details);

//echo("<br /><br /><br />".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."");
```

Comment: I've added the new value as suggested and it is still not working still classed as : Operating System: Unknown OS Platform

Comment: It works on my end. Try changing your code at the top to ```$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36';```. Also, what do you see if you echo ```$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']```?

Comment: nope still now working...still getting:

Browser: Unknown Browser
Operating System: Unknown OS Platform


Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36

Comment: Dear god, could you really not work this out for yourself?

Comment: its working..well.kind of I just tried it on my Windows 7 machine and it still displays Windows 10, I want it to detect any version of operating systems including Windows 10.

RiggsFolly - i'm fairly new to PHP so yeah I'm struggling

Comment: any ideas? how to detect windows 10 along with all the other OS's

Comment: Updated again. Note I've commented out the hardcoded user agent. This should now work - there's not really anything else I can offer. Take a few minutes to read each line, i've broken it down to the easiest way it would be written for someone quite new to PHP. Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it worked. Good luck!

Comment: AMO - it worked!!...many thanks for taking the time to help me. its working a treat on all 3 machines..Kindest regards!

Comment: @Amo is there any way to recognize windows server 10?

Answer (score 0):

Just add Windows 10 in your array:

```
$os_array = array(
    '/windows nt 10.0/i'    =>  'Windows 10',
    '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
    '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
    '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
    '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP     x64',
    '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
    '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
    '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
    '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
    '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
    '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
    '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
    '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
    '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
    '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
    '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
    '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
    '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
    '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
    '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
    '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
    '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
);
```

See [this fiddle](http://ideone.com/NhGrOs). ideone is not echoing any user agent, so I had to hardcode one, but if your user agent is present, this should work.

Comment: I've added the new value as suggested and it is still not working still classed as : Operating System: Unknown OS Platform

Comment: I just made a change, had a typo. Please check again.